# Как вывести в ng-view контент html файла из шаблона?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="block content margin-top10">
        <div class="col-2 block">
            <div class="thumb inline-block">
                <img class="block ava" ng-src="{{ data.avatarURL }}" alt="картинка"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 block border_gray information-user">
            <div class="col-10 block content-header">
                <img class="common-info-ico" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].commoninfoicoURL }}" alt="иконка"/><label for="">Общая информация</label>
                <a href="">Рекомендации верефикатору</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 block padding_10 float-left">
                <div class="item block gray_bottom float-left padding_tb10">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="place-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].placeicoURL }}"/><p class="">Живет в <a href=""> {{ data.pages[1].cities }} </a></p></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="status-married-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].statusmarriedIcoURL }}"/><p class=""> Состоит <a href=""> {{ data.pages[1].marriageStatus}} </a></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item block gray_bottom float-left padding_tb10">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="status-education-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].gradutedLearningIcoURL }}" alt=""/> <p class="">Учился в <a class="" href=""> {{ data.universities[0].name }} </a></p></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align padding_top10"><img class="scoool-ico margin_right10" src="" alt=""/><p class="">Ранее <a href=""> {{ data.schools[0].name + " , "  + data.schools[1].name }} 2014 - н.в</a></p></div>

                </div>
                <div class="item block gray_bottom float-left padding_tb10">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="work-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].workIcoURL }}" alt=""/><p class=""><a href=""> {{ data.pages[2].jobs[0].position  + " , " +  data.pages[2].jobs[0].name  }} </a></p></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="zaglushka margin_right10" src="" alt=""/><p class="">Ранее <a href=""> {{ data.pages[2].jobs[0].oldname  }} </a> в августе 2014 г.</p></div>

                    <div class="vertical-align padding_top10"><img class="income-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].incomeIcoURL }}" alt=""/><p class="vertical-align">Желаемый доход 2013 г.<a href=""> {{ data.pages[3].salary  }} </a></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item block float-left padding_tb10">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="smartPhone-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].smartPhoneURL }}" alt=""/><p class="line_h30">Мобильные устройства <a href=""> {{ data.pages[1].devices  }} </a></p></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align padding_top10"><img class="atention-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].attentionURL }}" alt=""/><p class="line_h30">Резюме обновлено 2 недели назад</p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-3 block side-bar float-left padding_10">
                <div class="item block gray_bottom float-left padding_top10">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="callPhone-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].callPhoneURL }}" alt=""/><a  class="inline-block" href=""> {{ data.pages[2].phones[0] }} <br> {{ data.pages[2].phones[1] }} </a></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align padding_top10"><img class="email-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].emailicoURL }}" alt=""/><p class="line_h26"><a href=""> {{ data.pages[2].emails }}</a></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item block float-left">
                    <div class="vertical-align"><img class="odnoklasniki-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].odnoklasnikiIcoURL }}" alt=""/><p class="line_h30"><a class="inline-block" href=""> {{ data.pages[1].alias }} </a></p></div>
                    <div class="vertical-align padding_top10"><img class="vkontakte-ico margin_right10" ng-src="{{ data.customIcon[0].vcontakteIcoURL }}" alt=""/><p class="line_h30"><a class="inline-block" href=""> {{ data.pages[2].alias }} </a></p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно вывести из файла директории conten/content.html в index.html в ng-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить роутер, при помощи `$routeProvider`. Вот пример:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // ...

        // Контент страница
        .when('/content', {
            templateUrl : 'content/content.html',
            controller  : 'contentController'
        });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <main ng-view></main>
</body>
```

**[Работающий пример тут](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBbsIHzQ9n0a01Umi3AJ?p=preview)**